# Implementing "Get directions" in a gwt application

Tags: google-maps, gwt, directions

I need to implement directions using Google maps inside my GWT web application.
Currently I'm using maps API v2 library.

I have several issues I have not been able to solve yet:

1. Include Get Directions panel (similar to the Google maps one)
2. Get list of streets names from the request.

PS How to implement mouse wheel zoom control?

Comment: You should definitely consider upgrading from API v2 to API v3.  v2 is deprecated and will probably stop working altogether from [May 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/).

Comment: @duncan Where to download API v3? All I found is the alpha version here [link](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: yes, that's the version you should use.  You don't need to download the Maps API, just the correct GWT version and specify to use API 3 as it says in [Adding the Maps script tag to your module XML file](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/wiki/GettingStarted#Adding_the_Maps_script_tag_to_your_module_XML_file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to easily implement zoom functionality:

```
final MapWidget map = new MapWidget(startLatLng, 12);
map.setSize("100%", "100%");

MapUIOptions options = map.getDefaultUI();
options.setScrollwheel(true);
map.setUI(options);
```

For more info check out [maps demo](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/HelloMaps-1.0.4/HelloMaps.html). You can checkout project code and test it in eclipse!

I'm still searching for solution to other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your mouse wheel zoom question

Implement [HasMouleWheelHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasMouseWheelHandlers.html) and its the [API's](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/MouseEvent.html) like getX(), getY(), getScreenX(), getScreenY() and do your zoom operations

Comment: I hoped there was a simpler way of doing this but I guess this will work too.

Comment: I found a simpler solution. I'll write it in a reply to post.